# What is the trading cycle of the market?

Tags: trading, day-trading, trading-volume

What is the ebb and flow of the trading cycle and at what times of the day and week does most trading take place? Do Mondays typically start the week out with heavy trading and the market up and then ease down with less trading during the week and then Friday heavier trading and close up? And what is the cycle for the day? Start up, then ease down and then close up? I know there is news and such that affect the market and not every day is the same but I am talking about day to day typical cycle without huge disrupting factors.  Newbie here trying to learn.

Comment: Which market are you talking about? Stocks? Commodities? Currencies? Bonds? And in which country? There isn't a single thing called "the market".

Comment: @MikeScott exactly.  Trading in Japan definitely takes place at a different time of day than it does in the US.

Comment: @RonJohn you want to see the trading volumes at Tel Aviv on a Friday as well!

Answer (score 3):

There are some general patterns in the US stock market but in and of themselves, none of them are going to make you any money.

Monday tends to be the highest volume day of the week since there's 3 days of news instead of one.  Tuesday tends to be the lowest volume day.

Mornings tend to trade higher volume due to accumulated weekend   and pre-market news.

Volume is higher after company specific news. good or bad (earnings announcements, M&A, new products/discoveries, etc.).  News drives price.

Volume is significantly higher when the market is falling (see 2008 and more recently,  the China problems in January 2018 or the 20% market correction in December of 2018). Fear panics the herd.

There is no repetitive cycle that you can reliably bet on.

Comment: I would add that some of the higher volume in the morning could also be attributed to overlapping market hours on the East Coast, i.e. NY, and Europe.

Comment: Also volume just means the amount of shares bought and sold, it's no indicator for whether or not things are going up or down.

Comment: Price indicates direction and velocity.  Volume only indicates liquidity not direction.  More often than not, price moves on volume.